# What are these wires called?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano, wires

I'm currently developing a quad copter for my school project and I am coming to the part where I am collecting all the parts before I assemble everything.

I have recently encountered a roadblock. I am going to solder an Arduino nano onto a strip board, but the problem is I cannot seem to find cables/wires to connect the nano to the module.

Excuse my ignorance, but where can I find these cables for soldering and what are they called?

[image]

Comment: Just wires? make sure they are copper and a smallish gauge and you'll be fine

Comment: "magnet wire" or "wrapping wire" is cheap and works well for bodging. ~30awg. old solid-core phone cables are another good source when on a budget.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they are an intentional part of the design they are *jumper wires*. If they are to correct a mistake in the design they are *bodge wires*.

They aren't anything special, just wire. They look to be in the range of 24 to 30 AWG and PVC jacketed.

You can buy it in any electronic store.

You can also salvage it from things like old SCART cables and similar things.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to wire your board with stranded wire, you can ask for ***NYAF*** and solder the edges with the tip. Otherwise you can ask for ***hook-up wires***.

But if you are using breadboard, which i recommend you to use solid wire, you can ask it as ***wire wrap***.

You can find them at an electronic store.

Answer (score 2):

Read this [tutorial](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/working-with-wire) about working with wires.

Sorry for the link-only answer, but I can't copy the article in full.

Answer (score 1):

> but where can I find these cables for soldering and what are they called?

hook-up wires.

pretty much any hardware stores should have it.